# Double Pendulum

Tags: notation

The equations of motions for the [double pendulum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) is given by

$$\dot{\theta_1} = \frac{6}{ml^2}\frac{2p_{\theta1} - 3\cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)p_{\theta2}}{16 - 9\cos^2(\theta_1 - \theta_2)}$$

and similarly for the other pendulum. In respect to what does the change in angle for the first pendulum refer to? Is it with respect to time? So that $\dot{\theta_1} = \frac{d\theta}{dt}$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The point always refers to the derivative with respect to time.

Answer (score 3):

The dot over a function or variable [Isaac Newton's notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_notation) for a derivative; in physics it always means a derivative with respect to time.

Variables with two or three dots, like $\ddot{\theta}$ and $\dddot{\theta}$, represent second and third time derivatives respectively.